# What's the best way to handle bug fixes in a gem dependency?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem (available on RubyGems) that relies on another gem. That dependent gem has a bug which I fixed recently. Unfortunately, that dependent gem is pretty much dead; it hasn't seen an update in years, and the owner isn't active on GitHub anymore *at all*, let alone making commits to this gem, so I don't expect my patch will get accepted—certainly not any time soon.

In light of that, what's the best way to handle the patched version of this dependent gem? Do I fork it and upload a new gem (with a new name) to RubyGems, and depend on that? Do I package my fixed version with my own gem somehow?

Comment: Interesting Q. How big is the part that you specifically require - In a similar situation, I've previously just copied the part I require into a single file (if it's less than 50 lines) with the license at the top of the file together with a link to the Github repo)...

Comment: i've made my own fork and then required it from git in the gemfile.

Comment: I like the question, although technically it probably should be flagged as "primary oppinion-based" ...

Answer (score 2):

First of all **check the bugged gem's LICENSE** (and your code's license, too - be sure things stay compatible).

Then - as you stated - you have multiple options:

- Include the fixed gem in your project and tell bundler/Gemfile to use the gem from that place.
- Fork, fix and tell bundler/Gemfile to use your git repository.
- Fork, fix and re-release (thats the `upstream` variant, embracing Open Source and its community).
- Monkey-Patching at runtime might be a solution, too (depends a bit on the code in question and your code-smell-tolerance. Basically: Don't do this at home! Leave alone, at work!).

I'd go with the the **fork, fix and re-release** solution, but you might have to make clear (in the README) that this gem needs a new maintainer.

It depends on what you mean with "best" (*...whats the best way...*). Easiest would probably be to monkey-patch, second to include the gem in your repository and tell bundler/Gemfile to pick it up from there. Also, no weird gem update will break your code. But then, if there ever should be fixes (by people like you :) ), you'll miss out on them.